# Как указать версию JDK в конфигурации Gradle?

Tags: gradle

⚠️ **Вопрос новичка (в Gradle)**

*То, что для Вас само собой разумеющееся, для меня на данный момент может быть отнюдь не очевидно.*

Первое приложение на Gradle, как обращаться с этим инструментом не понятно, какое отношение конкретно к моему приложению имеют абстрактные описания из документации - неясно.

IntelliJ IDEA сгенерировала мне такую конфигурацию:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
}

group 'loc.training'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

При попытке редактирования FXML файла IntelliJ IDEA говорит мне, что SDK не указан. Вернее, сообщение ссылается на JavaFX рантайм, но кнопка-ссылка предлагает мне установить именно JDK:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В списке JDK у меня уже есть, но каким-либо образом "выбрать" его нельзя (кнопка `Apply` неактивна). Видимо, нужно начать с того, что указать версию JDK в `build.gradle`, о чём и мой вопрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)

Существует 2 пути

изменить gradle.properties файл в каталоге .gradle в HOME_DIRECTORY

```
org.gradle.java.home=/path_to_jdk_directory
```

либо

изменить ваш build.gradle

```
compileJava.options.fork = true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = '/path_to_javac'
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста, я правильно понял, что в проектах, над которыми работают несколько человек и используется система контроля версий, `gradle.properties` коммитить не нужно?

Comment: у нас как. Архитектор или теам лид закидывает изменения и все остальные меняют у себя под себя и это уже да сливать нельзя. Вы же не узнаете чего неправильно если не последних увидите изменений. Так вот если изменения касаются всех то подобное решается с верху в низ или же ставите всех в известность. А так написали лиду что нужна такая-то опция в проект он посмотрит и если действительно нужна то даст разрешение или на его усмотрение.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял! Благодарю Вас ещё раз.